# ADF Mobile app deployed into Android emulator. Error: "Failed to initialize the AdfcContext"

Tags: android, sdk, performance, oracle-adf-mobile

I have the SKD Android Emulator. It was extremely slow, so I installed the Intel Hardware Accelerated Execution Manager (HAXM) and now it works really fast.

I have a very simple ADF Mobile application with 2 simple features, a "hello world" html page and a "hello world" amx page.

I deployed my app into the Android emulator in release mode, then I opened my app and it never stopped loading so I got out of the app. I tried to enter to the app again and I could enter to my html feature, but then when I tried to see my axm feature an alert popped up. It started loading and I don't know if it was going to finish loading, and then in a while:

```
"Failed to initialize the AdfcContext: {classname: oracle.adfmf.framework.api.Model; method: pushPageFlowScope; params: ;}"
```

When I deploy the Application I get this log warning:

```
"WARNING: No Resource Catalog enabled ADF components found to package"
```

I realized that I get this warning when I use the "Intel Atom (x86)" CPU in the Emulator. If I use the "ARM(armeabi-v7a)" CPU the axm page takes a really long time to load, but it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I found that "ADF Mobile only supports the ARM EABI v7a System Image". Here: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E35521_01/doc.111230/e24475/deploying.htm :(

Answer (score 0):

That's right. Adf mobile does have dependency with ARM.
Because when I try to install an adf mobile app into genymotion (another android emulator) , an error page shows that:

```
the app contains ARM native code...You should either build your code to x86 or install an ARM translation tool in your device.
```

Per my test, an emulator created by Android Studio is *quite* slow, too hard to use. 
Finally I fix this issue by this:[ARM_Translation](http://23pin.logdown.com/posts/691046-genymotion-use-arm-translation-on-6x-image)

Comment: "Finally I fix this issue by this" - consider copying relevant parts to your answer (or briefly describing), external links expire.